# Unable to Insert Feedback into Database

Tags: php, database, insert

I wrote the following code in baby steps, working with each thoroughly until it's worked. The last step was checking that a username/email does not exist and if true, inserting everything into a database. I got the code to send an email if there are not errors up until [5], but I cannot test anything beyond sending an email. When form is completed and sent, the page is cleared after the heading and does not proceed to the next page.

I have gone over the code as thoroughly as I possibly could, pulling up multiple sources and checking over general syntax with php validation tools. I don't have anything that comes up.

Connection:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('$db_host', '$db_user', '$db_pass', '$db_name');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
```

Body:

```
if (isset($_POST['process'])) {

$birthday = $_POST['year'].$dash.$_POST['month'].$dash.$_POST['day'];
$user_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pass']);
$confirm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['confirm']);

if ($_POST['user'] == '') {
    $errors[1] = 'Please enter your username.';
    } else if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,25}$/', $_POST['user'])) {
        $errors[1] = 'Usernames must contain 4 to 25 alphanumeric characters.';
    } else {
        $errors[1] = '';
    }
if ($_POST['email'] == '') {
    $errors[2] = 'Please enter your email.';
    } else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[2] = 'Email must be valid.';
    } else {
        $errors[2] = '';
    }
if ($_POST['pass'] == '') {
    $errors[3] = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else if (!preg_match('$\S*(?=\S{6,})\S*$', $_POST['pass'])) {
        $errors[3] = 'Passwords must be at least six characters long.';
    } else {
        $errors[3] = '';
    }
if ($_POST['confirm'] == '') {
    $errors[4] = 'Please confirm your password.';
    } else if ($_POST['confirm'] != $_POST['pass']) {
        $errors[4] = 'Passwords do not match.';
    } else {
        $errors[4] = '';
        $hash = password_hash ('$pass', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }

if (time() < strtotime('+13 years', strtotime($birthday))) {
    $errors[5] = 'You are not at least thirteen years old.';
    } else {
        $errors[5] = '';
    }

$to = $email;
$subject = 'Rabbit Showing and Breeding Association Registration Confirmation';
$header = 'From: RSBA Registration <registration@rsba.net>';
$message = 'Hello ' . $user_name . '!

You are receiving this email because you recently registered at Rabbit Showing and Breeding Association at http://rsba.net

Your confirmation code is: ' . $confirm_code . '

Please copy and paste the code into the account confirmation page or follow the following link to get started:
http://rsba.net/registration/confirmation.php?confirm_code=' . $confirm_code . '

Please disregard this email if you did not sign up for RSBA.

Thank-you,
Rabbit Showing and Breeding Association

This is an automated message. Do not reply.';

if ($errors[1] == '' && $errors[2] == '' && $errors[3] == '' && $errors[4] == '' && $errors[5] == '') {
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
    }

if($sentmail){
    include_once "../connect_info.php";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" . $user_name . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row['user_name']) {
        $errors[6] = 'This username already exists.';
        }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($row['email']) {
        $errors[7] = 'A user is already registered with this email.';
        }

    if ($errors[6] == '' && $errors[7] == '') {
        $result = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, hash, birthday, confirm_code, access_level)
        VALUES ('$user_name', '$email', '$hash', '$birthday', '$confirm_code', '0')";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $result)) {
            header('Location:sent');
            } else {
        $error[8] = '<span class="error">You cannot be registered.</span>';
            }
        }
    }

mysqli_close($con);

}
```

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: $errors[6] == '' && $errors[7] == '' ... where you set $errors[6], $errors[7] when no error is raised up? ... clean your code and logic

Comment: Are you sure the `$sentmail` is true? Dump it.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Btw, `htmlspecialchars` doesn't safeguard against SQL injection. Use prepared statements. If not, then you'll need to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` in its place, and maybe a dash of `stripslashes()`.